# When are the eigenvectors of an Hermitian matrix real?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-algebras

Consider a Hermitian matrix $M=M^\dagger$. Clearly, its eigenvalues are real, but what is the condition for the eigenvectors to be real as well?

Edit 1: I consider the entries of $M$ to be complex numbers. Moreover, I call a vector real if all its components are real numbers.

Edit 2: As pointed out in the comments, if $v$ is a real eigenvector of $M$, then also is $i v$. For this reason I might need to emphasise that I do not care about ``global'' complex coefficients.

Comment: On what space does $M$ act? And when is a vector real?

Comment: @Peter I was too sloppy, sorry. The entries of $M$ are complex number and a vector is real if it is in $\mathbb{R}^d$ (for some finite dimension $d$). I suspect the entries of $M$ need to be real in order for the eigenvectors to be real.

Comment: You still need to be a bit clearer if you want a sensible answer. Here's why. Suppose that $v \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ is an eigenvector for $M$. Now $iv \in i\mathbb{R}^{d}$ is an eigenvector for $M$ as well. I'm not sure how to fix this, but maybe a vector $v$ is *realifiable* if there is a complex number $\lambda$ such that $\lambda v \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$? Then you could ask for conditions on $M$ such that its eigenvectors are realifiable?

Comment: @Peter, I agree with you and I try to refine my question. I do not care whether there is an overall complex coefficient, so this would go in the direction of your definition I think. Then what should be the condition on $M$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have time to solve this right now. However it would help for others if you would edit your original question to include these clarifications and maybe include some of your attempts to solve the problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a necessary condition for an eigenvector to be real.

Let $v\in \mathbb R^n$ be a real eigenvector to the real eigenvalue $\lambda$. Split $M$ into real and imaginary part: $M=A+iB$, $A,B\in\mathbb R^{n,n}$.
Then
$$
Mx = (A+iB)x = Ax  +iBx= \lambda x.
$$
Splitting into real and imaginary parts again, it follows $Ax=\lambda x$ and $Bx=0$. That is, $v$ is in the null space of $B$, which is the imaginary part of $M$.

Of course, this is not sufficient to force an eigenvector to be real: the real matrix $\pmatrix{1 & 0\\0&1}$ has
has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors that are not real
$\pmatrix{1\\i}$, $\pmatrix{1\\-i}$. Multiplication by scalars does not help.

Comment: Thank you @daw , does it help if I add the assumption that there are no degenerate eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & i \\
-i & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$. Then $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ , but $ker(I-A)=span\{(i,1)^T\}$